# Windows 7 freezes randomly without BSOD

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have fully-patched windows 7 64bit on my laptop Asus B53J. I've been using it for a year and a half without much problems (well I had to send it to service once, they put in new motherboard). For some time now windows freezes randomly. It is a "hard freeze" - if I try to toggle caps lock, the light stays as it was. It seems to happen more when under heavy load, but sometimes it's just completly unexpected (like when browsing the web). There's neither BSOD nor any (suspicious) entry in the syslog. I tried resetting windows settings and running chkdsk and memtest. The latter two failed to run (probably because I have encrypted HDD). I've recently bought Kerbal Space Program and it ran fine for the first day, now it makes my laptop freeze after few minutes of running the game. I think it does not overheat. I see no dust inside and I tried to vacuum the fan. Also the air flowing outside is not that hot (I've managed to make it hotter before).

From what I've read it might be a RAM problem. <strike>I'll try to download memtest image and test it ASAP.</strike> I used memtest86 to test it and there were no errors. Do you have any ideas what else could cause this strange behavior, something that can be easily tested?

Comment: Bad memory without BSODs is extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I had that in my non-laptop computer on some cheap radeon GFX card, that was doing the thing you describe when browsing internet, watching movies and so on. I couldn't fix it with drivers, and inserting another radeon card made BSOD go away.

I can't say insert another gfx card because this is a laptop, just saying that i had similar problem and got that card refunded in the end.

Comment: Thanks. This laptop has two graphics so I'll try to switch to the Intel graphics and see if the problem is gone.

Comment: Oh i see it also is ATI card and that you can actually turn it off, they say. Good luck!

Comment: It seems great so far. Tried running Kerbal Space Program for 20 mins and it didn't freeze. What a benchmark!

Comment: Great, but you still have to send it back for repairs, no? Or maybe play with more recend AtI drivers first.

Comment: That's true. But if I know the cause and can reproduce the problem I can first reinstall and see if the problem is still present. If it wasn't, they wouldn't repair it. And I'd like to avoid reinstalling because I hate all this backing-up and copying files back. Also I use latest (2010) graphic drivers from ASUS website. Newer ATI drivers tend to break GPU switching.